# How to generate error message for form validation

Tags: angular6, angular2-forms, angular-forms

Trying to generate error message for form validation but i do not know how to generate error message.I want to create html element for error like"Please enter value dynamicaly below the input element by typescript.How do it?

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.ngForm = this._fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required,Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an email Validator that you can use.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.ngForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email:  new FormControl('', [Validators.required,Validators.email])
  });
 }
```

Then in your html

```
<form   [formGroup]="ngForm" (submit)="submitform()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" formControlName="name"/>
 <div *ngIf="ngForm.get('name').hasError('required')" style="color:red;">
   Name is required.
 </div>

 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" formControlName="email"/>
   <div *ngIf="ngForm.get('email').hasError('required')" style="color:red;">
   Email is required.
 </div>
 <div *ngIf="ngForm.get('email').hasError('email')" style="color:red;">
    Please enter the correct email or valid email.
 </div>

 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we create this error message(<span  *ngIf="ngForm.hasError('email', 'email')" style="color:red;">
      Please enter the correct email or valid email.
  </span>) by typescript after input element dynamic for all field??

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand the question but will do my best to answer. Because the formControlName is unique for each input, you will have to code a custom error for each unique formControlName <span  *ngIf="ngForm.hasError('name', 'required')" style="color:red;">
      Name is a required field.
  </span>

Comment: Please see revised answer, code validated in your stackblitz and should be able to copy and paste.